# I am facing some TS errors in NextJS form

Tags: reactjs, next.js, formik, yup

`I am using NexJS latest with Formik and Yup , when i run the code i receive below errors :

Errors:

1. Variable 'Myform' implicitly has an 'any' type.
2. Type 'string | FormikErrors' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
3. Type 'string | FormikErrors' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
4. Type 'string | FormikErrors' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.

```
"use client"

import { useFormik} from 'formik';
import  * as Yup from 'yup';

type Values = {
    date:Date
    checkbox1:Boolean
    radio1:Boolean
}

const Myform () => {
 
    const initValues:Values = {
        date: new Date(),
        checkbox1: false, 
        radio1:false,
    }

    const advanceSchema = Yup.object().shape({

        checkbox1: Yup.boolean().required("You must accept our terms and conditions!")
        .oneOf([true], "You must accept our terms and conditions!"),           

        radio1: Yup.boolean().required("Select Radio1")
            .oneOf([true], "Select payment Radio1."),     
        
        date: Yup.date().min(new Date(),
        "Please Select Correct Date").required("Select your preferred date"),                      
    })


    const formik = useFormik({

    initialValues: initValues,
    validationSchema: advanceSchema,
    onSubmit: async (values, actions) => {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
    actions.resetForm();      
    }})

    return (
        <form>   
            <label htmlFor='date'>
                {formik.errors.date && formik.touched.date ? 
                formik.errors.date :"Select your  preferred date"}
            </label>          
            <input type='date '{... formik.getFieldProps("date")} 
                placeholder='Select your preferred date'/>
            <p>Select Radio1</p>
            <input type="radio" {...formik.getFieldProps("radio1")} />
            <label htmlFor="radio1">
             {
                 formik.errors.radio1 && formik.touched.radio1 && formik.values.radio1 === false ?
                 formik.errors.radio1 : ""
              } 
            </label>    

            <input type="checkbox" {...formik.getFieldProps("checkbox1")}/>  

            <p> I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions</p>                          

            <p>  
                {formik.errors.checkbox1 && formik.touched.checkbox1 ? 
                formik.errors.checkbox1 : "" } 
            </p>

            <button type="submit" className={`
                ${formik.isSubmitting? 'bg-slate-400':"" }`}
                disabled={formik.isSubmitting}
            > 
                Submit
            </button>
        </form>
                 
   
  )
}

export default Myform
```

I trying to change the values of the validation Schema but still error not solved, any suggestions would be appreciated`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add a type annotation `React.FC` to tell that `Myform` is a functional component:

```js
const Myform: React.FC = () => {
  //...
}
```

other erros occurs because the conditional rendering in your code expects a `ReactNode`, but you are passing a `string` or `FormikErrors` object. you can wrap it with a fragment to make it ReactNode:

```js
<label htmlFor="radio1">
  {formik.errors.radio1 && formik.touched.radio1 && formik.values.radio1 === false ? (
    <>{formik.errors.radio1}</>
  ) : null}
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input ,  I did wrap it with fragments and the errors gone away but submit button its not working because if it work , i make console log the values.                                                                I think this error is coming from TS

Comment: @2div you have no errors now ?

Comment: you have to add `onSubmit` to your form opening tag `<form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>`

Comment: @2div what's your issue now?

Comment: Only first error fixed after adding React.FC ,                                            Remaining errors stop sowing when i added the fragment tag but submit button stopped working ! i have also add onSubmit={formik,handleSubmit} but submit not working